# Mapbox Clustering with GeoJSON file

Tags: android, swift, mapbox, geojson, markerclusterer

I am building a travel app that shows around 200 annotations on a specific mapView.
I have finished the iOS version and have now started creating the android version.

I previously used the MapBox example - Cluster point data.  With a GeoJSON file
https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/clustering/

Does anyone know if there is an android cluster point example that uses GeoJSON file?  Or if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

check out [this GeoJSON clustering example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/2f90c88df82fccc8bb6b1488465649d2ab479329/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/styles/GeoJsonClusteringActivity.java) in [the Mapbox Android demo app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapbox.mapboxandroiddemo&hl=en). The code is based on the upcoming 6.0.0 version of the Mapbox Maps SDK for Android. The demo app's `master` branch is using the 6.0.0-beta.7 version of the Mapbox Maps SDK for Android.

If you're using a pre-6.0.0 version, then check out [the old/"red" code that's using Filters instead of Expressions here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/commit/2f90c88df82fccc8bb6b1488465649d2ab479329#diff-27eda765289c006b7de369f44fa577d1)